# Incremental Loading in QScintilla Object

Tags: qt, qscintilla

I am using a an object of QScintilla and I am reading the file in QScintilla Object incrementally.

Header myEditor.h

```
class myScintilla: public QScintilla {
     public readFile();
};

#include  "myEditor.h"
void myEditor::readFile() {

   if (FILE* fp = fopen(ofilename.toLatin1(), "r")) {
    QTextStream ts(fp, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    int bufferSize =(1024* 1024)/2;
    do {
      QString s = ts.read(bufferSize);
      append(s);
    } while(!ts.atEnd());
}
```

Even after this change there will be still performance issue while reading large files. It took around

1) 25 seconds to read a file of size 1.5 GB. (Machine  cores 4 , 16 GB RAM)
   2 10 seconds of file of size 512MB  (on same machine)

Is there any way we can load the file in QScintilla object incrementally based on movement of scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

I found your question interesting so did a little bit of Googling on your behalf. It seems to me that while Scintilla exposes this functionality via the [Loader interface](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#BackgroundLoadSave), in fact the `QScintilla` class does not. To make this work, it seems that what you would have to do is use the `QScintillaBase` class to send the `SCI_CREATELOADER` message to the Scintilla control.

Edit: Also, you do not want to use `append` in a loop. That will cause all sorts of terrible things to happen. It will likely force rendering, some sort of indexing, etc. Before using my suggestion above, I would suggest that you instead build up a gigantic QString in memory and then set that at the end. Better to pre-allocate. That might be a little faster.

**FINAL ANSWER**

Edit #2: OK, it was bothering me that such an industrial strength editor component like Scintilla did not support this natively but it seems that the right way to do this is by using a combination of features:

1. You start with a document allocated using `SCI_ALLOCATE` where the number of bytes is the size of your file
2. You listen for the `SCN_UPDATEUI` event
3. Then, based on where the user is scrolling to, you load that data

It should be straightforward to map the above to `QScintillaBase` as a test.

Comment: As I understand I use object of QScintillaBase class and inside this object I should all the 1 ,2 ,3 steps of Final Answer. Since I am very new to QScintillaBase ,QScintilla  , if you could point me the sample example using the above approach as mentioned in your FINAL ANSWER

Comment: I only learned about QScintilla/Scintilla today! I know even less than you. All I'm saying is that it seems possible if you try my suggestion.